# Why is testcafe-docker.sh ignoring app-init-delay parameter?

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to build a docker-compose to include my app as a service and testcafe as another service. Both containers are build and initialized, but I can't get testcafe to wait until my app is available to start running the tests.

I've tried passing the --app-init-delay 30000 as a parameter to testcafe-docker.sh, but it ignores it.

```
entrypoint: ["/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh", "'chromium --no-sandbox'", "--app-init-delay 30000", "e2e"]
```

Also tried to use the script https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for  in the entrypoint or command before calling testcafe-docker.sh. In the command seems to get in conflict with the entrypoint command, when using it on the entrypoint I get testcafe to wait, but instead of running the tests ends with 'Operation timed out'

```
entrypoint: ['/script/wait-for', 'app:8080 -- "/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium --no-sandbox e2e"']
```

(Seems that all the parameters of wait-for need to be within the same entry of the array for it to work as an entrypoint script)

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: ./dist/docker/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./dist/docker/dependency:/dependency

  testcafe:
    container_name: testcafe
    image: testcafe/testcafe
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./test/e2e:/e2e
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./package-lock.json:/package-lock.json
      - ./script:/script
    entrypoint: ['/script/wait-for', 'app:8080 -- "/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium --no-sandbox e2e"']
#    entrypoint: ["/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh", "'chromium --no-sandbox'", "--app-init-delay 30000", "e2e"]
```

It seems that I'm very close to solving the issue with wait-for, but somehow my entrypoint syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simpler:

```
  testcafe:
    container_name: testcafe
    image: testcafe/testcafe
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./test/e2e:/e2e
      - ./package.json:/package.json
      - ./package-lock.json:/package-lock.json
      - ./script:/script
    entrypoint: ['/script/run.sh']
```

Create run.sh in the folder script and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

/script/wait-for app:8080 -t 60 -- /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium --no-sandbox e2e
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That makes it more readable, but it doesn't solve the issue. Testcafe still terminates with 'Operation timed out' without executing the tests

Comment: @MiguelSuárez You mentioned "but somehow my entrypoint syntax is incorrect" and I fixed that. Now for your script not working: the "wait-for" script has a default timeout of 15 seconds. Maybe your app needs more than that to start so try to increase the timeout: "/script/wait-for app:8080 -t 60 ..." (wait for maximum 1 minute)

Comment: There were two problems. 1. The script run must use a different interpreter #!/bin/sh  2. The script was that wait-for was doing an exec  "$@" which didn't work within the container. Replacing it with just "$@" call the command after waiting for app.

Comment: So the actual solution to the problem is to create a run.sh ```#!/bin/sh

/script/wait-for app:8080 -t 15 -- /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh 'chromium --no-sandbox' e2e``` And replace the exec "$@" with  "$@" in wait-for script